# DataTables and jquery adding modal to edit / delete links in each row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I am a newbie so please forgive me if this is an easy one..

I am trying to dislay a jquery confirmation box without much luck.. The regular javascript works fine..

I am using DataTables and have 2 images on the last column on the right, one edit and the other delete.

I tried a simple dialog as:

```
     ` $('#datatable tbody tr a.delete img').live( 'click', function () {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

  });`
```

In the html I have a div tage with the id of dialog..  but when I click the link I get an error saying "$("#dialog").dialog is not a function"

I have googled this error to death with no luck..  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have jquery ui referenced in your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.dialog()` is part of the **jQuery UI** plugin.

You got a demo here : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Load jQuery, then jQueryUI then your script :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#datatable tbody tr a.delete img').live( 'click', function () {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly..  and I understand what I did wrong from your post so its a double bonus..  :)

Comment: @Dennis : if the answer works for you, don't forget to _accept_ it with the _tick_ on the left. So people having the same problem than you in the future can have the answer quickly :)